# How to overlay boundary box from a Shapefiles into ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am following the example from here: https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2018/10/25/ggplot2-sf.html

How can I overlay a shape file on top of this that has a boundary box?

I downloaded the shapefile (Bounding Box) from here https://deims.org/d3ef6ead-0936-4f7b-907c-01758b7b7183 but when I try `(Map2<- Map + geom_sf(data=map1, fill = "lightgreen"))` I get an error `Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.`

I want the world map to have a box overlaid with the location of this sampling in a different colour (any colour)

```
 library("ggplot2")
 theme_set(theme_bw())
 library("sf")
 library("rnaturalearth")
 library("rnaturalearthdata")


 map1<- st_read("/Users/deims_sites_bboxesPolygon.shp")

 world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
 class(world)

 Map <- ggplot(data = world) +
 geom_sf() + coord_sf(xlim = c(120, 180), ylim = c(-60, 0)) +
 xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude") +
 ggtitle("World map", subtitle = paste0("(",  length(unique(world$admin)), " countries)"))


(Map2<- Map + geom_sf(data=map1, fill = "lightgreen"))
```

Comment: The first argument of each `geom` is the mapping, the data is the second. If you pass the data as the first argument you have to name it, i.e. try with `geom_sf(data = map1, ...)`

Comment: I tried to add it ```(Map2<- Map + geom_sf(data=map1, fill = "lightgreen"))``` but I could see the region marked so I made the main plot to focus in on Australia mainland by adding ```coord_sf(xlim = c(120, 180), ylim = c(-60, 0)) +```. When I run (Map2<- Map + geom_sf(data=map1, fill = "lightgreen"))``` after zooming into Australia I get an error ```Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.``` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This isn't an error message just a warning to inform you that there is already a coords layer present in your plot, i.e. when you call geom_sf for the second map it adds a second coords layer which overwrites the first. So to focus on Australia you have to adjust the limits in your second map too or only there.